# After reconnecting recessed lights, one stays on constantly. Why?

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement

We've been replacing drop down ceiling tiles in our basement, and had to disconnect the four light fixtures (pot lights) that are in each corner and reconnect them in order to place them through the new tiles. Everything is the same except for new tiles. Flip on/off switch and three respond appropriately.. except for the fourth.

We did this in the dark using flashlights due to having the breaker for this area of the house turned off for safety. The wiring is original to the house (1995)

Comment: Check the wiring at the light that stays on.  It must have a constant hot and a switched hot and you have those connected incorrect.....or it's possessed.

Comment: How is the switch wired?  The old way with just a black and white(hot) wire or the new way with black, red and white wires?  Or does the switch have two cables, one the power and to the lights?

Answer (score 3):

Since it worked before check the pictures you took before disconnecting stuff. I will take a SWAG: From your description you have not put it back the same way. All of the lights should be on the same black and white wires. The whites should all be connected together. The wire that is hot (should be black) goes to one side of the switch, the other side of the switch goes to the black wires that connect to the lights. If this is wrong post some pictures.

Comment: I think there is sarcasm in you post +1